# Playing a Song in MonoGame

Tags: monogame, audio

I'm trying to play a song in a MonoGame project, but it always gives me a weird error. Here is the (Very simple) code:

```
Song song = Content.Load<Song>("Song1");
        MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

But whenever I run the program, it says this:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect' to type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song'.'

Do you know why this happens? Any help would be appreciated! :D

Answer (score 2):

I believe the content importers are set up in a way that any .wav file must be loaded as a `SoundEffect`, and any .mp3 or .wma file must be loaded as a `Song`.

Your best bet is probably to convert the file to an .mp3, or load and play your music as a `SoundEffect`.